# ACF True/False Field, Only Run Code When Set To True

Tags: google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF google Maps to give direction to a Tender briefing location to clients.

I am using an ACF True/False field and would like to display the Google Maps address link only if the field is set to TRUE.

```
<span class="font-weight-bold">
    <b>Compulsory Briefing:</b>
</span>

<?php the_field('compulsory_briefing') ?><br/>
<span class="font-weight-bold">
    <b>Address [Google Maps] <a class="directions" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=<?php $location = the_field('briefing_address'); echo $location['lat'] . ',' . $location['lng']; ?>"> <?php _e(' Get Directions','roots'); ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your button in an if statement to check if the value is set to true or false:

```
<span class="font-weight-bold">
    <b>Compulsory Briefing:</b>
</span>

<?php if( get_field('compulsory_briefing') ): ?>
    <span class="font-weight-bold">
        <b>Address [Google Maps] <a class="directions" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=<?php $location = the_field('briefing_address'); echo $location['lat'] . ',' . $location['lng']; ?>"> <?php _e(' Get Directions','roots'); ?></a>
    </span>
<?php endif;?>
```

This is if your True/False field is "compulsory_briefing" change it this is not the case.

For more information on True/False fields in ACF [Click Here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/).